# Inserindo datas em php com PDO

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tendo problema ao inserir uma data no banco com PDO. Tenho uma classe espelho na minha tabela no banco:

```
class PaginaEntity {
private $id;
private $data;

public function __construct(){
    $this->data = date('d-m-y h:i:s A');
//gets and sethers
```

A classe para inserir:

```
class PaginaDao {
    public function inserirPagina(PaginaEntity $paginaEntity) {
        $conexao = new PDOUtil();
        $insert = $conexao->getStance()->prepare("INSERT INTO tabela_teste(data) VALUES(:data)");
        $insert->bindValue(":data", $paginaEntity->getData());
        $insert->execute();
    }
}
```

E tenho o form de teste:

```
include_once '../entity/PaginaEntity.php';
include_once '../dao/PaginaDao.php';
include_once '../configs/PDOUtil.php';

if(isset($_GET["acao"])) {
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $pagina = new PaginaEntity();    
    $daoPagina = new PaginaDao();
    $daoPagina->inserirPagina($pagina);
}
?>

<form method="post" action="testeInsercaoPagina.php?acao=ok">
    <label for="id">id da categoria</label>
    <input type="text" name="id"> <br/><br/> 
    <button type="submit">Gravar</button>    
</form>
```

O que acontece é o seguinte erro: [image: Imagem do erro]

Comment: Pelo que consegui ler, `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` resolve.

Comment: até coloquei assim $this->data = date('d-m-y h:i:s A', date_default_timezone_set('UTC')); o erro não existe mais porem ainda não insere.

Comment: Existe a definição do time zone no php.ini?

Comment: Ponha no inicio do codigo, antes de usar as funções de data.

Comment: Remova o 'A' da criação da data. Depois vc pode formata-la com o am/pm

Comment: configurei o phpini o timezone e o erro encerrou porem agora não insere o valor, lembrando que no banco eu coloquei varchar mesmo.

Comment: Qual erro aparece? O certo é usar timestamp para data e hora ou date para data. Vai ter problemas de ordenação e busca com varchar

Comment: não aparece nenhum erro, então coloquei varchar temporariamente mas vou mudar para timestamap as variáveis estão recebendo os seguintes valores id=1, que é um relacionamento e a data = 19-04-15 12:47:37

Comment: nesse formato de data posso deixar timestamp mesmo?

Comment: @rray mudei para timestamp e simplesmente inseriu, por que uma data não inseria em um varchar nem retornava erro? vc sabe

Comment: Deixe o formato Y-m-d H:i:s ou crie a data com o now() do mysql

Comment: pensei em deixar da seguinte forma vc acha que teria problema 'd-m-y h:i:s' em ordenações futuras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme o pessoal me passou nos comentários resolvi o erro da seguinte forma, peguei o caminho do php.ini no terminal`php --ini` logo depois adicionei o seguinte `date.timezone = 'America/Sao_Paulo'p` para configurar o mesmo, depois no meu banco de dados que tinha um varchar como valor a receber um dado e o mudei para timestamp conforme o @rray tinha falado.

obrigado a todos.